# Thinking in Java jar package search

Tags: java, classpath, importerror

recently I am reading about Thinking in Java.
that code in my PC is not working,even I set up class path.

"import static net.mindview.util.*;"
I need some help.

```
package iteration;
import  static net.mindviwe.util.*;
public class Exercise1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    int i=0;
    while(i<=100){
        print(i+"  ");
        i++;
    }

}
```

this is my class path :

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_05:

export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/ThinkingJava/TinkingInJava.jar:/opt/ThinkingJava/typeinfo-pets.jar:

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information an context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing, since your question is rather vague, but you put "classpath" as a tag...

When you run the JRE, you must specify the locations where the JVM can find the classes it will need.  In this case, your code uses the `net.mindviwe.util.*` package, which is probably in a JAR file named something like mindviwe.jar.  You can specify that the JRE should look in mindviwe.jar with the -classpath variable.  You can also use the CLASSPATH environment variable.

This is all discussed in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Of course, there also appears to be a typo in your package name where you transposed the 'w' and the 'e' (mindvi**ew** vs mindvi**we**).  This could also be your issue.

Comment: this is my class path                                              "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_05
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/ThinkingJava/TinkingInJava.jar:/opt/ThinkingJava/typeinfo-pets.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"                                           I still can not import  static net.mindviwe.util.*;

Comment: In what jar file is net.mindviwe.util defined?